# MongoDb: How to aggregate linked documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, Product and Stock

Below are example values

- Product

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63513c705f31b4bcb75b80ce"),
    "name" : "Coca-cola",    
    "stocks" : [
        ObjectId("63513c705f31b4bcb75b80d0")
        ObjectId("63513c705f31b4bcb75b80d1")
    ]
}
```

- Stock

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63513c705f31b4bcb75b80d0"),
    "count" : 9,
    "remaining" : 6,
    "costPerItem" : 10,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-10-20T12:17:52.985+0000"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63513c705f31b4bcb75b80d1"),
    "count" : 10,
    "remaining" : 3,
    "costPerItem" : 10,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-10-20T12:17:52.985+0000"),
}]
```

How do I query products whose sum of remaining stock (**remaining** field of stocks) is less than for example 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use:

1. `$lookup` with pipeline to get all the remaining stock count per stock
2. Sum it up using `$sum`
3. `$match` the relevant `product`s

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "stock",
      let: {stocks: "$stocks"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$in: ["$_id", "$$stocks"]}}},
        {$project: {_id: 0, remaining: 1}}
      ],
      as: "remaining"
  }},
  {$set: {remaining: {$sum: "$remaining.remaining"}}},
  {$match: {remaining: {$lt: 100}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b5xkKFiEKnm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't need remaining cost but remaining stocks

Comment: Still not working. The idea is one product can have many imported stocks

Comment: I updated the question for clarity

Comment: Yes it's working on the playground. But not on my machine

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is your mongoDB version?

Comment: It return documents but not expected one.
my mongoDB version is 5.0.8

Comment: I'm using https://studio3t.com/ to test it. The playground is working fine

Comment: Here is the playground data I tested with studio3t
https://mongoplayground.net/p/KV2MdxC31Sg

Comment: They are **products** and **stock**

Comment: It works now! My stock collection name is wrong. It should be ***stocks***
This is the working one
https://mongoplayground.net/p/FlLWY2a-x3a